# How to place a text on morris.js bar graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, morris.js

I have a morris.js bar graph. I want to place `count` on top of this graph.  I looked into [morris.js bar doc](http://www.oesmith.co.uk/morris.js/bars.html),  could not find any.

On hover it should display `value` but on top of bar it should display `count`. Is there a way to do that? something like the given image

[image]

Here is my code

```
Morris.Bar ({
  element: 'bar-example',
  data: [
    {mapname: 's1', value: 10, count: 3},
    {mapname: 's2', value: 4, count: 4},
    {mapname: 's3', value: 12, count: 13}
  ],
  xkey: 'mapname',
  ykeys: ['value'],
  labels: ['No. of days'],
  barRatio: 0.4,
  xLabelAngle: 35,
  hideHover: 'auto',
  barColors: function (row, series, type) {
    console.log("--> "+row.label, series, type);
    if(row.label == "s1") return "#AD1D28";
    else if(row.label == "s2") return "#DEBB27";
    else if(row.label == "s3") return "#fec04c";
  }
});
```

[Here is a link](http://jsbin.com/hahikeki/2/edit) where you can test it.

Comment: Did you find the solution for this problem? Wondering the same thing.

Comment: voidwalker & @Pooshonk: not yet..

Answer (score 9):

I just found this question whilst looking for the same solution. This is done in javascript / jquery.

I can share with you the code I am using which I discovered by trial, error and research.

```
function parseSVG(s) {
        var div= document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml', 'div');
        div.innerHTML= '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">'+s+'</svg>';
        var frag= document.createDocumentFragment();
        while (div.firstChild.firstChild)
            frag.appendChild(div.firstChild.firstChild);
        return frag;
    }

var theData = [
    {mapname: 's1', value: 10, count: 3},
    {mapname: 's2', value: 4, count: 4},
    {mapname: 's3', value: 12, count: 13}
  ]

Morris.Bar ({
element: 'bar-example',
data: theData,
  xkey: 'mapname',
  ykeys: ['value'],
  labels: ['No. of days'],
  barRatio: 0.4,
  xLabelAngle: 35,
  hideHover: 'auto',
  barColors: function (row, series, type) {
    console.log("--> "+row.label, series, type);
    if(row.label == "s1") return "#AD1D28";
    else if(row.label == "s2") return "#DEBB27";
    else if(row.label == "s3") return "#fec04c";
  }
});

var items = $("#bar-example").find( "svg" ).find("rect");
$.each(items,function(index,v){
    var value = theData[index].count;
    var newY = parseFloat( $(this).attr('y') - 20 );
    var halfWidth = parseFloat( $(this).attr('width') / 2 );
    var newX = parseFloat( $(this).attr('x') ) +  halfWidth;
    var output = '<text style="text-anchor: middle; font: 12px sans-serif;" x="'+newX+'" y="'+newY+'" text-anchor="middle" font="10px &quot;Arial&quot;" stroke="none" fill="#000000" font-size="12px" font-family="sans-serif" font-weight="normal" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,6.875)"><tspan dy="3.75">'+value+'</tspan></text>';
    $("#bar-example").find( "svg" ).append(parseSVG(output));
});
```

The output looks like this.

[image]

But what you can try, is change the values here

```
var newY = parseFloat( $(this).attr('y') - 20 );
```

to something like

```
var halfHeight = parseFloat( $(this).attr('height') / 2 );
var newY = parseFloat( $(this).attr('y') - halfHeight );
```

This change is untested, but will act as a good starting point.

Regards :)

Comment: Great Work, but there is undefined variable `theJson`  on line `var value = theJson[index].count;`

Answer (score 5):

You can extend Morris to achieve this. Please refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41018248/1351076) to see a full working snippet.

Add a property:

```
Bar.prototype.defaults["labelTop"] = false;
```

Add a prototype to draw the label:

```
Bar.prototype.drawLabelTop = function(xPos, yPos, text) {
    var label;
    return label = this.raphael.text(xPos, yPos, text)
        .attr('font-size', this.options.gridTextSize)
        .attr('font-family', this.options.gridTextFamily)
        .attr('font-weight', this.options.gridTextWeight)
        .attr('fill', this.options.gridTextColor);
};
```

Modify the `Bar.prototype.drawSeries` protoype, adding these lines (before the last else):

```
if (this.options.labelTop && !this.options.stacked) {
    label = this.drawLabelTop((left + (barWidth / 2)), top - 10, row.y[sidx]);
    textBox = label.getBBox();
    _results.push(textBox);
}
```

Then set the `labelTop` property to true in your Morris Bar config:

```
labelTop: true
```

Answer (score 1):

I find better to pass via jQuery to an empty p

This is the final result:
[Final Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OeKUf.png)

This is my code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 ">
      <p class="numero num1"></p>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 ">
      <p class="numero num2"></p>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 ">
      <p class="numero num3"></p>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 ">
      <p class="numero num4"></p>
   </div>
 </div>
```

**JS**
Below the chart code. *Remember to change **theData** variable to the one you're using in your code.*

```
 var b=1;
   jQuery('rect').each(function (i) {
      $('p.num'+b).text(theData[i].value); 
      b++;
    });
```

**CSS**

```
.numero{
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px !important;
  font-weight: 600 !important;
}
```

I also have added a class to each color.

Hope this helps anybody :)
Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Try by placing this code in **CSS**

```
.morris-hover{position:absolute;z-index:1000;}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but not just on hover but all the time it should display `count` on top of bars

Answer (score 0):

Here is a start, its a bit hacky, but it gets the job done:

**JS**

```
    var graphData= [
    {mapname: 's1', value: 10, count: 3},
    {mapname: 's2', value: 4, count: 4},
    {mapname: 's3', value: 12, count: 13}
  ]; //store this to its own var so we can access the counts later


var bar=Morris.Bar ({
  element: 'bar-example',
  data:graphData,
  xkey: 'mapname',
  ykeys: ['value'],
  labels: ['No. of days'],
  barSizeRatio:0.4, //I think you meant barSizeRatio, not barSize
  xLabelAngle: 35,
  hideHover: 'auto',
  barColors: function (row, series, type) {
    //console.log("--> "+row.label, series, type);
    if(row.label == "s1") return "#AD1D28";
    else if(row.label == "s2") return "#DEBB27";
    else if(row.label == "s3") return "#fec04c";
  }
});


//first, find the width of a bar
//this is bar-example width, divided by three, times barSizeRatio
var barWidth=($('#bar-example').width()/3)*(0.4);

//now each thru each bar (rect)

jQuery('rect').each(function (i) {
  var pos=$(this).offset();
  var top=pos.top;
  top-=20; //originate at the top of the bar

  //get the height of the bar
  var barHeight=bar.bars[i];
  top+=barHeight/2; //so we can now stick the number in the vertical-center of the bar as desired
  var left=pos.left;
  //move it over a bit
  left+=barWidth/2; 
  //-size of element...
  left-=10;//should approximately be horizontal center

  $div=jQuery('<div class="count" style="top:'+top+'px;left:'+left+'px;" />'); 
  $div.text(graphData[i].count); //get the count
  jQuery('body').append($div); //stick it into the dom
  console.log($div);
});
```

and some CSS to style the divs

**CSS**

```
.count{
  position:absolute;
  width:10px;
  height:20px;
  line-height:20px;
  color:white;
  font-weight:bold;
  }
```

hopefully you can run with that to create the exact effect you are looking for

[image]

Comment: Any demo link to your example?

Answer (score 0):

[enter link description here](https://codepen.io/iqulyhyx/pen/eYYXEEg)

```
      barColors:function(e){
      if(e.label=="2014"){
                        return "#EA7756";
                }else if(e.label=="2015"){
                        return "#91D180";
                }else{
                        return "#FDAA4C";
                }
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

@chiliNUT @abi1964 I placed multiple charts but I am having a problem w/the CSS.  The data, bar height etc. all works fine but the #s are being stacked on top.  I've tried every iteration of position in the CSS.  Ideas or a Fiddle how to fix this?

[image of multiple graphs w/#'s stacking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kQod.jpg)