# How to display count value of each category of Y axis in a graph using Morris.Bar function?

Tags: html, razor, morris.js

I am displaying data in graphical format and I am using Morris.Bar function in my cshtml page. The Y axis has categories namely: Performance, Maintainability, Others, Portability, Reliability and Security.

I am using the following function:

```
Morris.Bar({
    element: 'category-bar-chart',
    data: JSON.parse(''[{"y":"Performance","a":23},{"y":"Maintainability","a":106},{"y":"Others","a":98},{"y":"Portability","a":27},{"y":"Reliability","a":87},{"y":"Security","a":14}]'),'),
    xkey: 'y',
    ykeys: ['a'],
    labels: ['Violation'],
    xLabelAngle: 43,            
});
```

But currently it is not displaying the value for each category at the top of each bar. May I know what property I can add to get the values at the top of each bar?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's no built-in parameter to display the value on top of each Bar.

But you can extend Morris to add this parameter. I've extended Morris, adding a `labelTop` property for Bar charts. If set to `true`, a label with the value is added on top of each Bar (I restricted this property for non stacked Bar, as there's multiple values with stacked Bar).

Usage:

```
labelTop: true
```

Please try the snippet below to see a working example:

```js
(function() {
  var $, MyMorris;

  MyMorris = window.MyMorris = {};
  $ = jQuery;

  MyMorris = Object.create(Morris);

  MyMorris.Bar.prototype.defaults["labelTop"] = false;

  MyMorris.Bar.prototype.drawLabelTop = function(xPos, yPos, text) {
    var label;
    return label = this.raphael.text(xPos, yPos, text).attr('font-size', this.options.gridTextSize).attr('font-family', this.options.gridTextFamily).attr('font-weight', this.options.gridTextWeight).attr('fill', this.options.gridTextColor);
  };

  MyMorris.Bar.prototype.drawSeries = function() {
    var barWidth, bottom, groupWidth, idx, lastTop, left, leftPadding, numBars, row, sidx, size, spaceLeft, top, ypos, zeroPos;
    groupWidth = this.width / this.options.data.length;
    numBars = this.options.stacked ? 1 : this.options.ykeys.length;
    barWidth = (groupWidth * this.options.barSizeRatio - this.options.barGap * (numBars - 1)) / numBars;
    if (this.options.barSize) {
      barWidth = Math.min(barWidth, this.options.barSize);
    }
    spaceLeft = groupWidth - barWidth * numBars - this.options.barGap * (numBars - 1);
    leftPadding = spaceLeft / 2;
    zeroPos = this.ymin <= 0 && this.ymax >= 0 ? this.transY(0) : null;
    return this.bars = (function() {
      var _i, _len, _ref, _results;
      _ref = this.data;
      _results = [];
      for (idx = _i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; idx = ++_i) {
        row = _ref[idx];
        lastTop = 0;
        _results.push((function() {
          var _j, _len1, _ref1, _results1;
          _ref1 = row._y;
          _results1 = [];
          for (sidx = _j = 0, _len1 = _ref1.length; _j < _len1; sidx = ++_j) {
            ypos = _ref1[sidx];
            if (ypos !== null) {
              if (zeroPos) {
                top = Math.min(ypos, zeroPos);
                bottom = Math.max(ypos, zeroPos);
              } else {
                top = ypos;
                bottom = this.bottom;
              }
              left = this.left + idx * groupWidth + leftPadding;
              if (!this.options.stacked) {
                left += sidx * (barWidth + this.options.barGap);
              }
              size = bottom - top;
              if (this.options.verticalGridCondition && this.options.verticalGridCondition(row.x)) {
                this.drawBar(this.left + idx * groupWidth, this.top, groupWidth, Math.abs(this.top - this.bottom), this.options.verticalGridColor, this.options.verticalGridOpacity, this.options.barRadius, row.y[sidx]);
              }
              if (this.options.stacked) {
                top -= lastTop;
              }
              this.drawBar(left, top, barWidth, size, this.colorFor(row, sidx, 'bar'), this.options.barOpacity, this.options.barRadius);
              _results1.push(lastTop += size);

              if (this.options.labelTop && !this.options.stacked) {
                label = this.drawLabelTop((left + (barWidth / 2)), top - 10, row.y[sidx]);
                textBox = label.getBBox();
                _results.push(textBox);
              }
            } else {
              _results1.push(null);
            }
          }
          return _results1;
        }).call(this));
      }
      return _results;
    }).call(this);
  };
}).call(this);

Morris.Bar({
  element: 'category-bar-chart',
  data: [
    { "y": "Performance", "a": 23 },
    { "y": "Maintainability", "a": 106 },
    { "y": "Others", "a": 98 },
    { "y": "Portability", "a": 27 },
    { "y": "Reliability", "a": 87 },
    { "y": "Security", "a": 14 }],
  xkey: 'y',
  ykeys: ['a'],
  labels: ['Violation'],
  xLabelAngle: 43,
  labelTop: true
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="category-bar-chart"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer