# Show count on top of morris chart bar?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, morris.js

I want to show some data analysis using morries chart bar and my bar is showing perfectly according my data but i am facing one issue that the count should be show in every chart bar.

I have following script to show chart:

```
<?php 
    $first_month_query  = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT COUNT(`ft_booking_date`) as day_count, DATE_FORMAT(`ft_booking_date`, '%d-%b') as Booking_date FROM `jps_final_tickets` WHERE `ft_event`= '$getEventId' AND `ft_booking_date` >= DATE_FORMAT(curdate(), '%Y-%m-01') GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(`ft_booking_date`, '%d-%b')") or die(mysqli_error($con));
    $json_data_current_day = array();
    foreach( $first_month_query as $result){
        $json_array_first_day['y']= $result['Booking_date'];  
        $json_array_first_day['a']=$result['day_count'];
        array_push($json_data_current_day, $json_array_first_day);
    }
    ?>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group" id="day-wise"></div>
    </div>



<script>
Morris.Bar({
    element: 'day-wise',
    data: <?php echo json_encode($json_data_current_day); ?>,
    xkey: 'y',
    ykeys: ['a'],
    labels: ['Members Count']
});
</script>
```

[image]

So as per above screenshot it is working fine but now i want to show member count on every each bar, right now the member count showing on hover.

So, how can i show member counts on every bar.

Comment: have look at this link [stack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23537788/how-to-place-a-text-on-morris-js-bar-graph)

Comment: @webpic, nothing i found in this link.

Answer (score 1):

```js
Morris.Bar({
  element: 'bar-example',
  data: [{
    device: 'iPhone',
    geekbench: 136
  }, {
    device: 'iPhone 3G',
    geekbench: 137
  }, {
    device: 'iPhone 3GS',
    geekbench: 275
  }, {
    device: 'iPhone 4',
    geekbench: 380
  }, {
    device: 'iPhone 4S',
    geekbench: 655
  }, {
    device: 'iPhone 5',
    geekbench: 1571
  }],
  xkey: 'device',
  ykeys: ['geekbench'],
  labels: ['Geekbench'],
  barRatio: 100,
  xLabelAngle: 35,
  hideHover: 'always'
});

var data = [{
  device: 'iPhone',
  geekbench: 136
}, {
  device: 'iPhone 3G',
  geekbench: 137
}, {
  device: 'iPhone 3GS',
  geekbench: 275
}, {
  device: 'iPhone 4',
  geekbench: 380
}, {
  device: 'iPhone 4S',
  geekbench: 655
}, {
  device: 'iPhone 5',
  geekbench: 1571
}];

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  var a = $('svg text:nth(' + (i+data.length-1) + ')').clone();
  
   var b = a.children('tspan')[0];
  b.textContent=data[data.length-i-1].geekbench;
  b.setAttribute('dy', 24);
  $(a).appendTo($('svg'))
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.oesmith.co.uk/morris-0.4.1.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="bar-example"></div>
</body>
```

Moris use event delegation to show the hover.As a result you'd better copy `$('morris-hover morris-default-style')` for some times.Or append text for each rect bar as below.

```
let data=<?php echo json_encode($json_data_current_day)[i]; ?>;

for(let i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    $('#day-wise svg > rect:nth-child('+i+')').append('<text>'+data[i]+'</text>')
}
```

I've made an example .http://codepen.io/fanyer/pen/aJYMMa

Comment: Can you explain where should i put this script.

Comment: I have just put this into script. but it is not giving anything.

Comment: where should i paste your code, in php or in script? i have pasted into script it not read [i].

Comment: what is i here??

Comment: I update this answer , if  you solve your problem, please vote me up

Comment: I just realize it myself and its style is totally bare. Cause Moris.js is customed so upperly that many things are not included by it.

Comment: I thought you'd better explore my code in codepen link above.

Comment: sorry it is not working for me. but thanks for response and finally i  found the answer.